# How to reduce the program execution time in PHP and how to improve the performance

Tags: php, mysql

I am running mysql select queries  3500 times in a for loop and perform operations on the values returned by the queries in PHP. that process takes 16 seconds to execute for loop. any suggestion to reduce the execution time and improve the performance. thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code of your loop?

Comment: Querying in a loop is almost always a bad idea. Please show us your query and what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Try to minimize the amount of queries, do you really need 3500 queries or can you select all rows in a single call?

If not, you can gain some performance by using prepared statements PDO gives you a easy to use interface for that.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Please paste some code if i need to be more specific :)

Comment: Good solution - PDO prepare kind of precompiles the statement but with dynamic variables, so if you *do* have to run it 3500 times, it will still be far quicker.

Comment: Actually I am running queries based on the time period. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your MySQL select so you only execute it once, not 3500 times. Tell us the queries in question, and we might be able to help you do it

Comment: Actually i run the queries based on the time period. for example I am getting user logins number daily since 2001. thanks for your suggestions and give some suggestions to Refactor MYSQL

Comment: @KMK - Show us the SQL queries, and we might be able to refactor it for you - the most obvious solution for a time period query is with a group by - but without knowing the queries, there's not a great deal more that we can actually do to help.

Comment: Hi Mark Baker, I need code to export the data from Google visualization table to Excel and PDF. Please help me.I would waiting for your response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem as you.

The amount of mysql connections you open during the operation will be critical. Try execute them all in one connection. If you need multiple connection, use mysql_pconnect instead.

Avoid using commands that mysql can't cache. (e.g. NOW()) For a list of such commands, check out the link here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html
I achieve this by changing my query from real time to hourly basis.

Avoid big statements as much as possible, try breaking it down to smaller one and use code to tie them up together. The smaller the statement, the easier to cache, thus lead to better performance.

Finally, if you need quick solution, memcached is a very good and quick to implement solution.

The general guideline is that, if you can execute less and simpler statements, the better.

Answer (score 0):

use a select query where key in (val1,val2,....,val3500)
in that way you will exectute only two query instead of 3500